# My Smoke simulation has this buggy blocky shadow

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, shadows, render-passes, mantaflow

I have been tackling this problem for the last 2 days and I can't find any solution to it.
So, I baked this smoke sim and test rendered it, It has some weird blocky shadow and reflection, I thought it was just a random bug, so I closed blender opened it again, and re-render it, it outputs the same result. I tried to delete the flow object and replaced it with something else, it still outputs the same result. Tried to delete the domain and re-do it, nothing changes. I am very confused on what's happening here.
[image: COMPOSITE]

I have 3 view layers/render passes:

- The smoke itself:
  [image: The Smoke itself]
- Shadow Catcher

[image: Shadowcatcher]

- Reflection Catcher/Glossy Indirect
  [image: Gloss Indirect]

Maybe you guys can figure what's the problem, here's the Blend file link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P84r9d5UbGE-TWvDeEQERqG2zU_gcYc2/view?usp=sharing
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have an NVIDIA GTX 1650 and Ryzen 5 4600h